# Computer shudown during upgrade, Ubuntu not booting

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, boot-failure, package-management

My computer shutdown because of ***critical temperature reached***. I was upgrading my Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10. Now, Ubuntu is not starting up.

Comment: Is there some sort of error message when you boot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to run a [LiveCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) to boot and use [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) to fix things.

1. Get yourself a [Ubuntu LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)
2. Boot from it
3. Mount broken partition:

   ```
   mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
   ```
4. Mount virtual filesystems:

   ```
   mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   ```
5. chroot to the mounted filesystem:

   ```
   mount --bind /usr/ /mnt/usr 
   chroot /mnt
   ```

Now you are 'inside' your normal partition and all commands you run are from that partition, same goes for the modifications! So you can fix your installation now.

Normally you can continue/fix a failed apt-get using:

```
apt-get install -f
```

You might want to rerun:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Depending on your problem (eg apt-get itself is broken due to the interrupted upgrade) you might to run some other commands in your chroot-ed environment as well. If you do not succeed you need to provide more details.